# Ruby : how to bundle install some new gems without updating existing ones

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

I'm working on a legacy Rails app. and need to install a few new gems.  We are setup to use the bundle tool.  However I've been warned that we cannot do a simple bundle install as any updates to existing gems will put the system into an invalid state.

So how do I use bundle to add some new gems without touching any of the existing ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do `bundle install`, Bundler only concerns itself with new gems or new versions that you explicitly specify in your `Gemfile`. It'll also remove any gems from `Gemfile.lock` that you remove from your `Gemfile`.

If you do `bundle update`, then you end up with the problem that you describe in your question. It'll update existing gems, especially if no specific version is specified for each gem.

Here is a more in-depth explanation: http://viget.com/extend/bundler-best-practices. There is an "INSTALL VS. UPDATE" section that you'll probably want to read.

**Update**

To make sure that you're in full control of your gems' versions, I recommend referencing specific versions in your `Gemfile`. You can do the same with Git references by indicating a specific revision.

Examples of what I've had to do recently to get `sunspot_cell` working in my environment, based on [this post](http://cbpowell.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/indexing-rich-documents-with-rails-sunspot-solr-sunspot-cell-and-carrierwave-cookbook-style/):

```
# The ability to do full document indexing has some "special needs" right now
gem "sunspot", git: "git://github.com/sunspot/sunspot.git", ref: "f5a6b54e8c12a500acf37cfa3b4091bc57b75db0"
gem "sunspot_solr", git: "git://github.com/sunspot/sunspot.git", ref: "f5a6b54e8c12a500acf37cfa3b4091bc57b75db0"
gem "sunspot_rails", git: "git://github.com/sunspot/sunspot.git", ref: "f5a6b54e8c12a500acf37cfa3b4091bc57b75db0", require: "sunspot_rails"
gem "sunspot_cell", git: 'git://github.com/zheileman/sunspot_cell.git', ref: "0c0b7f980b8c46bd272fe0a5a31d2c259bebe36e"
gem "sunspot_cell_jars", "0.4"
gem "progress_bar", "0.4.0"
```

As you can see, I want for the `sunspot` gem to use `github.com/sunspot/sunspot`, with the specific `f5a6b54e8c12a500acf37cfa3b4091bc57b75db0` revision.

For the `sunspot_cell_jars`, I want to use version `0.4` of `sunspot_cell_jars`.

This keeps `bundle install` from messing anything up, and you stay in full control of versions.

Comment: Ok I ran "bundle install --no-deployment" as this is a development machine.  It looked like it installed the new gems OK.  Now I am getting a problem with passenger (we are using Apache as the front end), "git://github.com/Goin/dm-migrations.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install` (Bundler::GitError)".  dm-migrations is also one of the gems listed in the existing Gemfile, and running "bundle show dm-migrations" indicates it is installed.  So somehow the bundle install has affected other settings?  Please help.

Comment: You can always revert your changes. I answered your question the best I could based on the info you provided. I do not have experience with Passenger. Sounds like this could be another question with more specifics.

Comment: Sure I'll post a new question based on the passenger problem.

Comment: Do any of your gems in the `Gemfile` have a `git` option? Perhaps you should post relevant parts of your `Gemfile` in the new question.

Comment: I would check to see what commit was referenced in your `Gemfile.lock` for the Git-based gems and reference those specific commits in your `Gemfile`. I'm going to update my answer with a proposed best practice.